# Custom Property for PDF File

Tags: pdf, count, aspose, customproperty

I would like to add total page count as a custom property like ms word does as follow.

[image]

Is it possible to similar things for pdf? I am also using aspose for file conversion. I converter many kind of file types to pdf but if we want to show also the document's pagen count as the custom property.

Comment: We would like to share with you that required feature is not supported in Aspose.PDF API, at the moment. However, we have logged a feature request with ID **PDFNET-44709** in our issue management system. We will notify you as soon as the ticket will be investigated and resolved. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @FarhanRaza thank you for your reply. We will waiting for this feature.

Comment: You're welcome. We will let you know once some significant progress is made in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Aspose Newsgroup:

```
//open document
Aspose.Pdf.Document pdfDocument = new Aspose.Pdf.Document("Test.pdf");

//set properties
pdfDocument.Metadata["xmp:Nickname"] = "Nickname";

pdfDocument.Metadata["xmp:CreatorTool"] = "Test Value";

pdfDocument.Metadata["xmp:CustomProperty"] = "Custom Value";

//Convert to PDF/A compliant document
pdfDocument.Validate("log.xml", PdfFormat.PDF_A_1A);

pdfDocument.Convert("log.xml", PdfFormat.PDF_A_1A, ConvertErrorAction.Delete);

//save output document
pdfDocument.Save("output_XMP.pdf");
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you for your reply but this is XMP metadata. You can see them in the properties window of the acrobat reader.I want to create a customer property in windows's detail window.

Comment: Could it be this stuff here: https://apireference.aspose.com/net/pdf/aspose.pdf.facades/pdffileinfo/properties/index otherwise I would try the aspose newsgroup directly.